# Unable to run iOS app after updating XCode 15.2

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, macos

I got the error

> Unable to install */ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app on
> 4F1AE59B-FCFB-45F9-B872-11B58146E56D. This is sometimes caused by a
> malformed plist file:

The build installed fine on the Android Emulator but failed on iOS simulator, clearing 'Developer > Build caches and index' from Mac Storage didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue by updating flutter to the latest version 3.16.7, previously i was trying to build using flutter version 3.13.x which didn't work. After updating flutter running a flutter clean and pub get, i was able to build successfully.